# Multi-label prediction using DNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tflearn

I'm trying to predict several labels for a given text. It works well for a single label, but I don't know how to implement confidence score for multi-label prediction.

I have data in the following denormalized format:

```
┌────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ id │  Topic   │  Text  │
├────┼──────────┼────────┤
│  1 │ Apples   │ FooBar │
│  1 │ Oranges  │ FooBar │
│  1 │ Kiwis    │ FooBar │
│  2 │ Potatoes │ BazBak │
│  3 │ Carrot   │ BalBan │
└────┴──────────┴────────┘
```

Each text can have one or multiple topics assigned. 
So far I came up with this.
First, I prepare my data - tokenize, stem, etc.

```
df = #read data from csv
categories = [ "Apples", "Oranges", "Kiwis", "Potatoes", "Carrot"]
words = []
docs = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    stems = tokenize_and_stem(row, stemmer)
    words.extend(stems)
    docs.append((stems, row[1]))

# remove duplicates
words = sorted(list(set(words)))

# create training data
training = []
output = []
# create an empty array for our output
output_empty = [0] * len(categories)


for doc in docs:
    # initialize our bag of words(bow) for each document in the list
    bow = []
    # list of tokenized words for the pattern
    token_words = doc[0]

    # create our bag of words array
    for w in words:
        bow.append(1) if w in token_words else bow.append(0)

    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[categories.index(doc[1])] = 1

    # our training set will contain a the bag of words model and the output row that tells which catefory that bow belongs to.
    training.append([bow, output_row])

# shuffle our features and turn into np.array as tensorflow  takes in numpy array
random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)

# trainX contains the Bag of words and train_y contains the label/ category
train_x = list(training[:, 0])
train_y = list(training[:, 1])
```

Next, I create my training model

```
# reset underlying graph data
tf.reset_default_graph()
# Build neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Define model and setup tensorboard
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
model.save('model.tflearn')
```

After that I'm trying to predict my topics:

```
df = # read data from excel

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    prediction = model.predict([get_bag_of_words(row[2])])
    return categories[np.argmax(prediction)]
```

As you can see, I pick maximum of `prediction`, which works well for a single topic. In order to pick multiple topics, I need some confidence score or something, which can tell me when to stop, because I can't blindly put an arbitrary threshold.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a softmax activation on your output layer you should use a **sigmoid** activation. Your loss function should be **cross entropy** still. This is the key change you should need for multi-class.

The problem with softmax is that it creates a probability distribution over your outputs. So if class A and B are both strongly represented, softmax over 3 classes might give you a result like [0.49, 0.49, 0.02], but you would prefer something more like [0.99, 0.99, 0.01].

The sigmoid activation does exactly this, it squashes the real-valued logits (the value of the last layer before a transformation is applied) to a [0, 1] range (which is necessary to use the cross-entropy loss function). And it does that for each output independently.

Comment: I've added `activation='sigmoid'` to all layers and defined my loss function as `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` in the tflearn.regression. I'm still getting not normalized values like `[[8.9157884e-06 9.7833133e-01 8.3094416e-03 3.3070598e-02 4.0033931e-01]]`

Comment: The sigmoid is only necessary on the last layer, I'm not sure what you used before, but the previous layers didn't absolutely need to change (not that using sigmoid on a fully connected network is necessarily wrong). Those values are all in the [0, 1] range though, they look correct. You're getting `[0.00, 0.90, 0.00, 0.03, 0.40]` It looks to be predicting the 2nd class strongly, and is kind of unsure about the 5th class. These values will not be normalized to 1, each value will range in [0, 1] independently, and can be **roughly** considered a confidence per class.